# How to get the filename that is redirect as input from shell in c++

Tags: c++

Hello I'm doing this:  `myprogram < filename.txt`

I want to get the filename I typed over the shell, how can I do that?.

Comment: AFAIK, that's totally impossible.

Comment: Then, how can I get the integers from the file I redirect??

Comment: @user3329539: The file is your standard input.

Comment: The think does not have to have a name at all. For example it may be output of another process via anonymous pipe.

Comment: If it is a requirement to know the filename I would change to supply it as an argument and read the file within the program, but then the program can only read files and not pipes e.g.

Answer (score 3):

There is no portable way to do this. **That's because that information is useless for most purposes.** The file handle `0` (POSIX API), [`stdin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) (C API) or [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) (C++ API) (each is wrapper for the preceding) is what you have to read from.

There however is a way that works on Linux (including Android) and some other unices that have the `/proc` filesystem.

That provides symlinks to files open by each process in `/proc/`*pid*`/fd/`*fh* where *pid* is process ID or special string `self` for current process and *fh* is the file handle. Standard input is the handle 0, standard output is the handle 1 and standard error is the handle 2.

So to get name of standard input, you can

```
readlink("/proc/self/fd/0", outbuf, outbufsize);
```

See [readlink(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readlink).

This *might* work. It does not have to. For example the file might be in a different namespace. Or it may give you a name, but it may just describe non-filesystem object like a socket or anonymous pipe. Or it may give you a name, but you may not be able to open it or do anything else with it, because you may lack appropriate permissions. The calling process had those permissions and gave you the open handle and that's the only think you can reliably work with.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible in a general way. It might though be possible in some very specific situations and some operating system. On Linux, your process's input file (if it is indeed a file) will most probably be symlinked from `/proc/[procid]/fd/0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and you shouldn't want to. Your program receives the file's contents, not its name. Access those contents by reading from `STDIN` (using `std::cin`).

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in a any kind of portable way.

The shell is feeding the contents of the file to your program in a very straightforward way.

No meta-data or other information is transmitted.